# Why quantum angular momentum operator is just like classical, but with operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, definition

In all angular momentum discussions in textbooks I saw them define angular momentum operator with the cross product of position and momentum, and, after opening in components, they transform position and momentum in operators. I can't see why this should be the angular momentum even in quantum realm. Couldn't it be something else with classical limit going to the cross product of position and momentum? Why it has to be like this?

Comment: Another thing that constrains the expression is that it has to be the generator of rotations, just like momentum and translations. So you know the commutators have to satisfy the usual rule.

Answer (score 0):

In Classical Mechanics the position  and linear momentum components $\,x_{k},p_{k}\,$ are scalars and so along any axis they commute
\begin{equation}
x_{k}\,p_{k}-p_{k}\,x_{k}=0
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
In Quantum Mechanics the position  and linear momentum components $\,x_{k},p_{k}\,$ along any axis must satisfy the relation
\begin{equation}
x_{k}\,p_{k}-p_{k}\,x_{k}=i\hbar
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
Equation (02) could not be satisfied by scalars but by operators represented by matrices. Moreover these matrices could not be even finite.

Of course, the meaning of equation (02) is that the operators $\,x_{k},p_{k}\,$ along any axis don't commute and so it's impossible to have exact values simultaneously.

The classical definition of orbital angular momentum is valid in Quantum Mechanics too, but the $\,x_{k},p_{k}\,$ are hermitian operators. So in coordinates
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{J}=
      \begin{bmatrix}
         J_1 \vphantom{\frac12}\\
         J_2 \vphantom{\frac12}\\
         J_3 \vphantom{\frac12}
       \end{bmatrix}
   \equiv
      \begin{bmatrix}
         x_2p_3\!-\!x_3p_2 \vphantom{\frac12}\\
         x_3p_1\!-\!x_1p_3 \vphantom{\frac12}\\
         x_1p_2\!-\!x_2p_1 \vphantom{\frac12}
       \end{bmatrix}  
   =\ \mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}   
\tag{03}
\end{equation}
Using (02) we can prove that
\begin{align}
   \left[J_2,J_3\right] & = J_2J_3-J_3J_2 = i\hbar J_1
\tag{04.1}\\
   \left[J_3,J_1\right] & = J_3J_1-J_1J_3 = i\hbar J_2
\tag{04.2}\\
  \left[J_1,J_2\right]  & = J_1J_2-J_2J_1 = i\hbar J_3
\tag{04.3}
\end{align}
Formally expressed as
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{J}\boldsymbol{\times} \mathbf{J}\  = \ i\,\hbar \,\mathbf{J}
\tag{05} 
\end{equation}
Above equation leads to the result that the angular momentum components $\,J_{k}\,$ take only integer or half-integer values (the orbital angular momentum components take integer values only, while spin angular momentum components take integer or half-integer values).

Answer (score 0):

defining operators in quantum mechanics is just another (and certainly widely acceptable and popular) tool or a manifestation to determine the observable quantities. If you don't like operators, it's fine. Don't work with that. You can still determine the momentum, angular momentum, and any observable that you want. For that approach you must have a plot or information regarding the probability of finding that quantity in some range for a given state and in order to find that probability distribution for that quantity, you must be able to write that given state as a linear combination of a series of functions( in terms of operators these are the eigenfunctions of that particular operator associated with desired observable). for example- if you wish to find the avg momentum, we don't have to go for operator tool. Just writing the given state and it's complex conjugate as a fourier integral and a further little maths will give us the average momentum.In the same way, any quantity can be evaluated.

Comment: I have no problems with operators. My problem is with this particular definition of angular momentum. Why it could not be something else that, in the ''macro'' world, turns out to be the classical RxP? It's almost like ''axiomatic'' in the way it is presented. ''Oh, it would be alright if it was the operator version of RxP... So, we will take it to be exactly that.''